# Does PHP have a construct similar to .NET's DataSet?

Tags: php, .net, mysql, dataset

How can I implement a `DataSet` in PHP like .NET?

I want this class to read data from database only once, then I should be able to use the data without connecting again to MySQL to run queries.

```
select * from user
```

When I run this query on the `DataSet` the data is fetched from memory.

How can I implement this mechanism in PHP?

Answer (score 5):

You could push your data into an array like this:

```
$result = mysql_query( 'select * from user' );

$results = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    array_push( $results, $row );
}

mysql_close();
```

Then you can do whatever operations you want on the array...

```
foreach( $results as $record ){
    $foo = $record['col_name'];
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the `DataSet` / `DataTable` data container classes of .NET which can work in disconnected mode.

A `DataReader` is kind of a cursor and needs to have the connection open in order to move through the result set of the underlying query.

In PHP you could do this:

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "addressbook";
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

  $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_address_book";
  $result = mysql_query($SQL);

  while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print $db_field['ID'] . "<BR>";
    print $db_field['First_Name'] . "<BR>";
    print $db_field['Surname'] . "<BR>";
    print $db_field['Address'] . "<BR>";
  }

  mysql_close($db_handle);

}
else {
  print "Database NOT Found ";
  mysql_close($db_handle);
}

?>
```

Comment: i'm sorry.i don't know this mechanism implemented with DataSet or DataTable.when i run a query i don't want connect to mysql and read from mysql. i want to fetch all data from table in first time and store it to memory and when i need to some data read those from memory.

Comment: yes so what you need is the equivalent to a .NET DataSet, NOT a DataReader :) you can edit your question. I can't help you more as I am not good at all in php :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think php can provide what you're looking for as it's very much text code and HTML driven, so you don't get the fancy GUI objects like you do in .net. [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/Structures_DataGrid/redirected) provides a lot of source code that will produce data grids, that you could possibly investigate, all stored in code like arrays etc. I'm relatively new to php, so maybe someone would disagree...